# Is possible pass a variable from a tpl file to php file?

Tags: php, smarty

Is possible pass from php to tpl with this:

PHP:

```
  $smarty->assign('variable',$foo);
```

TPL:

```
  {$variable}
```

But i don't know if is possible pass a variable from tpl to php...

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it, but take a look to [get_template_vars()](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.get.template.vars) and [{php}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php) tag. Maybe it is what you are looking for.